# Get values from a text file with XML nodes in Powershell

Tags: regex, xml, string, file, powershell

I'm having some difficulties in taking values ​​from a .txt file following a standard in powershell.

My .txt file has this structure:

```
<arquivo>teste.exe</arquivo>   <caminhoArquivo>C:/teste</caminhoArquivo>
<arquivo>carro.zip</arquivo>   <caminhoArquivo>C:/sistema/res</caminhoArquivo>
<arquivo>logs.txt</arquivo>   <caminhoArquivo>C:/log</caminhoArquivo>
<arquivo>servicos.txt</arquivo>   <caminhoArquivo>C:/sistema/res</caminhoArquivo>
<arquivo>modelos.jpg</arquivo>   <caminhoArquivo>C:/sistema/modelos</caminhoArquivo>
<arquivo>binarios.zip</arquivo>   <caminhoArquivo>C:/nova pasta</caminhoArquivo>
<arquivo>config.lua</arquivo>   <caminhoArquivo>C:/server</caminhoArquivo>
```

I would like to get the value between `<arquivo>` and `</arquivo>` e.g. "teste.exe", and the value it between `<caminhoArquivo>` and `</caminhoArquivo>`  e.g. "C:/teste" with a `foreach` for each line of the text file, but I am unable to do this. I already tried it with a regex but I did not have success. Could help a newbie in powershell with this problem?

Thanks ! :D

Comment: function restaurarLixeira
{

  $example = "<arquivo> dasdasdasd <arquivo>"
  $pattern = "(?<=.*<arquivo>)\w+?(?=<arquivo>.*)"

$result = [Regex]::Match($example, $pattern)

$result.Value
Write-Host $result.Value.ToString()
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems that the lines are XML nodes you could try it like the following which wraps them inside a `root` node and then converts them to XML

```
Get-Content $pathToYourFile | 
  % {
    $root = [xml]("<root>$_</root>")
    @{
        arquivo = $root.root.arquivo
        caminhoArquivo = $root.root.caminhoArquivo
    }
  }
```

which returns a list of hashtables

```
Name  : caminhoArquivo
Value : C:/teste

Name  : arquivo
Value : teste.exe

Name  : caminhoArquivo
Value : C:/sistema/res

Name  : arquivo
Value : carro.zip

...
```